# Image byte[] length varies from server to server

Tags: c#

I have an image embedded as a resource in my project, and code that saves the image to the db using nhibernate as a byte[] (byte array).

I then have code to assert that the image in db matches the image I selected to save.

When this runs in my local dev environment, both byte[]'s have the same sequence and length.

```
Assert.IsTrue(imageInDb.SequenceEqual(imageOnFile), errorMessage);
```

So to review, I have an image embedded as a local resource, and I save this to db using nhibernate as a byte[], to get the byte[] I use this:

```
imageOnFile = Properties.Resources.MyImage.ToByteArray();
```

It saves it correctly and has a length of 66510. However on one of my test agents the imageOnFile length is being reported as 65413.

This is strange because the exact same code is being used to get the data initially for the save, and then for the assertion. So if the byte array len is 65413 during the assertion I would expect it to have saved a 65413 during the save operation.

When I recheck the code again using local dev environment, clearly it just works.

What am I missing?

EDIT: The initial image gets saved with len 66510 from my local dev environment, then later the imageOnFile (from embedded resource) running now on a test agent reports byte[] len on disk 65413. So it seems it could be file system related?

Comment: Did you check what the difference is and where?

Comment: Look at the two different drive's cluster sizes. I suspect that they are different between your local and the testing agents drives, meaning the size occupied on the disk will be different (More details [here](http://superuser.com/questions/704218) and [here](http://superuser.com/questions/66825)

Comment: @BerndLinde A byte array in memory should have the same size no matter what the drive's cluster sizes are.

Comment: @Magnus, that is correct yes, but JL is talking about the stored image, check his last edit :)

Comment: @BerndLinde: it doesn't matter whether the data is in memory or on the disk, it will still have the same length. The block/cluster size on a disk only affects space efficiency of the storage; the file system hides/abstracts this from a process simply reading the file. It is not plausible that cluster size differences has anything to do with the issue the OP is seeing. And this is especially true given that neither of the reported numbers are a multiple of any plausible block size.

Comment: If you are simply dealing in a sequence of bytes, it will never change length assuming correct code. But if you are actually decoding and re-encoding the image, it certainly could change length legitimately. Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's not possible to offer any specific advice about the problem.